# Python: Add row into pandas dataframe with array as column value instead of multiple rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to handle with a table of following form:

```
example = {'Assumptions': 1, 'Index': 5, 'Proposition': '¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)', 'Premisses': [4, 3], 'Rule': '∧I'}
```

The command

```
example = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

gets:

```
   Assumptions  Index Proposition  Premisses Rule
0            1      5  ¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)          4   ∧I
1            1      5  ¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)          3   ∧I
```

but my aim is to get some table of following form:

```
   Assumptions  Index Proposition  Premisses        Rule
0            1      5  ¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)          [3, 4]   ∧I
```

Is their a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a list first, then construct the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([example])
```

Output:

```
   Assumptions  Index Proposition Premisses Rule
0            1      5  ¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)    [4, 3]   ∧I
```